# deep nesting of swf works one level deep only

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, loader

I've a simple swf loader routine within each SWF file.

`a.swf` loads/adds `b.swf` and `b.swf` loads/adds `c.swf`

When I run `b.swf` I clearly see `c.swf` loaded

but when I run `a.swf`, I see `b.swf` but not `c.swf`

**Note:** I'm getting the reference of class, instantiating it manually and adding it to display but works 1 level deep only. following routine is reused for each loader.

**Edit** it works if I use `this.onResult(loader.content)` instead of `this.onResult(new classRef());` but i need to get it working for the `classRef`

```
    public function load():void {
        loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
        loader.load(new URLRequest(this.url));
    }

    private function completeHandler(event:Event):void {
        var className:String = getQualifiedClassName(loader.content);
        var classRef:Class = loader.contentLoaderInfo.applicationDomain.getDefinition(className) as Class;
        this.onResult(new classRef());
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public function load():void {
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
    loader.load(new URLRequest(this.url), new LoaderContext(false, ApplicationDomain.currentDomain));
}
```

Comment: i tried that but it didn't work, the only way it works if I use `this.onResult(event.target.content)`, sad to know. let me iterate the problem for more clarity. The nested SWF just fails to display (loads fine) it's child SWF or in other words grand child fails to add to display

Comment: I isolated the problem by creating simple 3 fla files (a.fla, b.fla, c.fla each with associated .as files) and it works perfectly in both cases `classRef` or `event.target.content`, so that means there's something wrong with my code. behind the scenes the `new classRef()` gets transported to the parent document class and gets added there. Funny `new classRef()` doesn't work but `event.target.content` works in my code.